# Force Close when app is upgraded

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm working on a new version of my app and added another table to the database. In the emulator it works perfectly, but in the phone occours force close if I install over the old version.

If I install the version of the play store and after install my developer version over her, the app gives force close. If I remove the app from the phone and put only the development version, works just fine.

I do not know simulate the upgrade the application to the emulator, I cant do test of the method ONUPGRADE. But the code that is there to new table, there is also in onCreate (working), so do not see why giving error.

What I need:
1 - One way to see the exception causing force close on the phone, any way to get this information from the device;
2 - Any way to test the upgrade of the app on the emulator;

Note: I updated the version in the manifest, so I think the phone would do an upgrade (or not?)

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at the below link,hope this will be helpfull

[onUpgrade() sqlite database in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159210/onupgrade-sqlite-database-in-android)